# BPF filters load half word and byte of a packet. Syntax explanation required

Tags: linux, tcp, bpf

The following code is from BPF filters (Berkley Packet Filters). in the first line, `ldh [12]`, it loads [12] `something` of a packet but documentation of `BPF filter` says `ldh` is used to load  a half word of a packet   and in third line it loads [23]  `something` of a packet but documentation says `ldb` is used to a load byte . I like to know what is `12` and `23` along with `ldh` and `ldb` respectively.

```
  ldh [12]
  jne #0x800, drop
  ldb [23]
  jneq #6, drop
  ret #-1
  drop: ret #0
```

the above code only allow tcp packets to enter into the tcp-ip stack(socket).

Explanation of BPF filters https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to pchaigno's answer, here is an explanation on the concrete values that your program loads.

In your case the program processes the packet starting from the Layer 2 (Ethernet) (other socket families/types can start at layer 3 or 4 headers). It goes like this:

```
ldh [12]           # Load two bytes at offset 12
                   # Offset 12 is the 2-byte long Ethertype field of the
                   # Ethernet header

jne #0x800, drop   # If those two bytes are not 0x800
                   # (i.e. packet is not IPv4), go to “drop”

ldb [23]           # Load one byte at offset 23
                   # Offset 23 is offset 9 in the IPv4 header
                   # (23 minus 14 bytes for the Ethernet header)
                   # This is the 1-byte long Protocol field

jneq #6, drop      # Load Protocol number, if different from 6
                   # (IANA number for TCP), go to “drop”

ret #-1            # Keep packet

drop: ret #0       # Drop packet (“truncate to 0 length”)
```

Comment: offset 12 brings us at the start of `Header Checksum`  before that is the half word while makes `Time to Live` and `Protocol` /  `jne #0x800, drop` means `0x800!=16_bit_half_word` which includes both `Time to Live and Protocol` how the the above code isolates `Time to Live` from half word which also includes protocol which is only what we need to compare with `0x800`  ?

Comment: Or the full word should be 0x0000-0xFFFF so in a way 0x8000 is what is meant when written as 0x800. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Offset 12 does not bring us to the Header Checksum. We count from the beginning of the Ethernet (L2) header, not the IPv4 (L3) header, so the loaded field is the Ethertype, as mentioned above. It tells you if you have IPv4 or IPv6 or ARP or [whatever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType). There is no comparison with the Time to Live at all. The Protocol is accessed by loading one byte at the offset 23 (14 for L2 header + 9 within IPv4 header).

Comment: ok I get it. and what about ldb [23] is 23 offset into which field. do u know where I can look at the offsets which explain `ldb [23]` like offset 23 is gives us one byte of tcp protocol. which diagram should I refer to ip or ethernet frame or tcp?

Comment: Your BPF program has no notion of the different layers, so all offsets are _from the beginning of your packet_ (in your case, this is the beginning of the [Ethernet header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)). What is at offset 23 may vary for different kind of packets (e.g. ARP will differ from IPv4). But the filter first checks that the packet _is_ IPv4 (since we drop if Ethertype is not 0x800), so we _know_ that L3 is IPv4 starting at offset 14. From there we want to reach the Protocol field, which is offset 9 in the IPv4 header, so we load one byte at offset 14 + 9 = 23.

Comment: thanks makes sense now. also is there a way to check http header in payload with bpf filter. can I compare http header hex string by loading and comparing with packet offset? does bpf filter support regex?

Comment: BPF is basically like assembly, so you can parse more but you have to implement all yourself. HTTP is far from trivial. You need to determine you have a HTTP request (port check + `HTTP/<version>` + `GET ...`). You may have to check the L3/L4 headers length to account for header options. You cannot have regex, because your filter cannot have back edges (no jump back, so no loops). You may want to have a look at other tools, for example based on eBPF (see [this example](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/tree/master/examples/networking/http_filter)).

Answer (score 0):

12 and 23 are **offsets into the packet**. So `ldh [12]` loads a half word at offset 12 in the packet.

This is referred to as the "Addressing mode" in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt) and, in this case, the bytecode is using the "Addressing mode 1".

Comment: offset 12 brings us at the start of `Header Checksum` before that is the half word while makes `Time to Live and Protocol` / `jne #0x800, drop` means 0x800!=16_bit_half_word which includes both `Time to Live` and `Protocol` how the above code isolates `Time to Live` from half word which also includes `protocol` which is only what we need to compare with 0x800 ?